# jQuery click() and changing the checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Behold the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RA3GS/4/

If you check on the checkboxes manually, you see that they say they are checked when they are checked and remain checked. However, if you push the test buttons you'll see that they either say they are checked, and then become unchecked, or say that they are not checked, and say they are checked.

Here is the problem: if I choose not to set the checked value before hand, the checkbox is correctly checked at the end, but the clicked function incorrectly states that it is unchecked. If I do set the checked value, then the `click()` function correctly states that the checkbox is checked, but then some other event (un)helpfully unchecks the checkbox at the very end.

The jsfiddle is a test; in my real implementation I will have no control over the `click()` function on the input element, so it is not merely a matter of changing the login in the click function.

This is the behavior I want, exactly:

- You click on the button.
- Any `click()` function is triggered and believes the element to be checked.
- All other events believe the checkbox to be checked.
- When everything is said and done, the checkbox is still checked.

### Simpler example

I've put a simpler jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/49jUL/

Without changing the `status` function, I want the console to display identically no matter which checkbox you check. Current output is:

**clicking on manual**

> A tester received the following event change
> Value:  100  Checked:  true
> A tester received the following event click
> Value:  100  Checked:  true

**clicking on controller**

> A tester received the following event click
> Value:  100  Checked:  true
> A tester received the following event change
> Value:  100  Checked:  false

I find it interesting that if I click on the manual radio button, `change` is called first and *then* `click`, whereas if I trigger click, `click` is called and *then* `change`.

Note that when I've tried calling it as `$target.change().click()` then it simply calls `change`, then `click`, then finally `change` again with `checked` set to false.

Comment: I got lost in the check uncheck checking of the unchecked checked, but for thoughts, could it be that using "click" is misleading and maybe focus might be better ? or more thoughts, depending on what you want to do with these checkboxes use "dummy" checkboxes and leave these real ones as you want them = all checked - but not visible to the page ? sorry if no use

Comment: Just an FYI: `checked` is a property, not an attribute, so I would recommend using the appropriate [accessor and mutator](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for the "checked" status: `$('#checkBoxElId').prop("checked");` and `$('#checkBoxElId').prop("checked", true/false);`. The "checked" *attribute* does not change after the initial loading of the checkbox. See the link for more explanation.

Comment: I must use click. Basically, in the final version of this the checkboxes are hidden, so *if* the checkboxes had a click action, I need to trigger it as it was not directly clicked.

Comment: @Cory looks like you have the answer. Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: D'oh, nevermind, looks like I'm still running into problems. I'll update my question when I have it clearer in my mind.

Comment: Ok, good luck. Is this maybe a browser discrepancy issue? Perhaps a bug in the version of jQuery you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>From my comment--</sup>

The `checked` field is a *property*, rather than an *attribute*, so I would recommend using the appropriate accessor and mutator for the "checked" status:

```
$('#checkBoxElId').prop("checked");
```

and

```
$('#checkBoxElId').prop("checked", true/false);
```

Alternatively you can use the `is()` function with the `:checked` pseudo selector to see if it's checked:

```
$('#checkBoxElId').is(':checked');
```

The "checked" attribute does not change after the initial loading of the checkbox. See [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) on `prop()` for more information about the state of checkboxes.

---

**EDIT: Solution**

After finding [a bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3827#comment:9) explaining this behavior, I did a little experimentation with the workaround documented in the bug's comments: the use of `triggerHandler("click")` instead of calling `click()`.

`click()` is just a shortcut for `trigger("click")`, which will trigger a matching event on all elements found by the selector, and will also invoke the native handler. `triggerHandler("click")`, OTOH, will only trigger the event for the first element found by the selector, and will prevent the default (native) behavior from occurring. It's the native behavior that is messing with the "checked" state of the checkboxes. By avoiding it, you get the desired behavior.

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49jUL/3/) with my solution.

Comment: Trying prop but it still isn't working. See the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49jUL/ . I want console output to be the same whether you click on "Manual", "Controlled", or "Controller".

Comment: @JordanReiter: This is actually a known bug (with a workaround): http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3827#comment:9. Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49jUL/3/

Comment: Yay! triggerHandler is the answer! Add that to your answer and we have an accepted answer. :)

Comment: @JordanReiter: I added it to my answer with some further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not be simply triggering the click on the check box, you need to verify the current status, and then act accordingly:

```
$('#pushbutton').on("click", function() {
    var $obj = $('#myCheckBoxID');
    $obj.prop('checked', !$obj.prop('checked'));
    alert('now check is: ' + $obj.prop('checked'));
});
```

See this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/j85S6/)

#### EDITED

Followed improvement given by ThiefMaster on the first comment.

Comment: Why not use `var cb = $('#mycheckbox'); cb.prop('checked', !cb.prop('checked'))`

Comment: Hmm... learning every day! That's why I love Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Tks! Did some reading to understand it better and just updated the Fiddle and the answer!